# C# Checking colour on screen error: Parameter must be positive and < Height. (Parameter 'y')

Tags: c#

My code:

```
private bool SearchPixel(string hexcode)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

            Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcode);

            for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                    label1.Text = "Current colour: " + currentPixelColor;
                    if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                    {

                        label2.Text = "You are on the colour!"
                        return true;

                    }
                }
            }
            label2.Text = "You are not on the colour!";
            return false;
        }
        catch { return false; }
        
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchPixel("#hexcolourgoeshere");
    }
```

Error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Parameter must be positive and < Height. (Parameter 'y')
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at coolgame.Form1.SearchPixel(String hexcode) in C:\Users\b\Desktop\Form1.cs:line 27
   at coolgame.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\b\Desktop\Form1.cs:line 49
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Tried a lot of things from Google but no luck, same with some things from stackoverflow and nothing worked. I have no idea what is wrong, also the label1 text is always changing to the new colour it works fine it's just the exception is happening every second

Comment: Check your `for` loop conditions for the typo.. One of them causes an infinite loop because the loop condition isn't checking anything subject to change within the loop.

Comment: The error is in this line: `for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)`

Comment: Also (once you've replaced `x` with `y` in your second `for`), you should compare `x` and `y` to `bitmap.Width` and `bitmap.Height` instead of `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width` and `.Height` for 3 reasons: 1. it's more logical, since you use `x` and `y` to access `bitmap`. 2. `bitmap.Width` and `bitmap.Height` can't change while your code is executing. 3. `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen` indicates the size of all you monitors, but you make the `bitmap` only from the main one. With a multi-monitor PC, the code would throw, even after replacing `x` with `y`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error in the second for loop

change :

```
  x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
```

To  :

```
  y < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
```

Like This

```
for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
                {
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an excellent way to learn how to debug.

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
```

And it clearly states that the error is on `y`. If you put your mouse over the `y`, you'll see `1080` (probably, depending on your screen resolution), which is, indeed, out of the [0, 1079] range.

"But I just checked that it was within the range just before..."

If you put your mouse over `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height`, you'll see, as expected `1080`. But if you put your mouse over `<`, you'll see that the condition is `true`. **That**'s not expected...

What are you comparing `1080` to? Put your mouse on the variable and you see... `0`. And we saw just before that `y` was `1080`. Then you'll see your typo. In your second `for` loop, your condition checks the value of `x`, instead of `y`.

So you just have to replace

```
for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
```

with

```
for (int y = 0; y < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked. I don't know if this is the best thing to do, what do you guys think

```
try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

                Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcode);

                while (true)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
                        {
                            Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                            label1.Text = "Current colour: " + currentPixelColor;
                            if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                            {

                                label2.Text = "On colour : Yes";
                                return true;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    label2.Text = "On colour: No";
                    return false;
                }
                


            }
            catch { return false; }
```

Comment: The `while (true)` you added changes nothing (since the code either returns or throws in the first `while` iteration. The program doesn't crash because it's in a `try` block (which already existed). And even if the exception is catched, it still is thrown, which it should not (the reason being a typo: the interior `for` checks its condition on `x` instead of `y`).

Comment: Yeah, that's not really a fix, that's just ignoring that there's an issue. I recommend you never solve your issues by catching errors and throwing them away, unless you know for sure it doesn't matter, or if you aren't left any other choices. The answer was just you had a typo in your `for` loops, the above answers have the fix.